# How to use pycharm to run an application in remote spark cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I have installed PyCharm on my local system and have configured it to run spark applications in local mode in windows.

My spark cluster is in a remote Ubuntu box.

**How can I run a spark application in the remote spark cluster, which is on Ubuntu, from my locally installed PyCharm which is on Windows?**

My goal is to run the application in a remote cluster so workarounds are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm is already setup for this. Ideally you want to setup a *deployment* and a *remote interpreter* for your setup, ideally via `ssh`.

This allows you to upload your codebase to the cluster (so that the `pyspark` driver has access to it), but run it from your laptop. Remote interpreter then takes care of resolving dependencies on the cluster. 
Have a look here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html and here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html.

NB: Before you start configuring the remote interpreter, it's better to install `venv` or `conda` on your cluster and create a virtual environment, so that you don't have any dependencies or outdated packages. You then point the remote interpreter config to the `python` binary of the environment, such as `/app/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python`.

Comment: how to use spark-submit to run python file in pycharm?